# Volterra Integral equation for Cauchy Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the Cauchy problem:
$$y'\:=\:4\cdot x^3+x\cdot y^2$$
$$y\left(0\right)=0$$

Write the Volterra Integral equation equivalent to the Cauchy problem, the formula for the sequence of successive approximations and for the start function $y\left(0\right)\equiv 0$ calculate the first two successive approximations.

I'll be honest here, I have no clue what this is in reference to or how to even start this problem. Can someone give me a tip or two, tell me where to look, or help me solve this and explain the steps? I'm desperate here, and I really want to understand, not just solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is also known as Picard iteration, just integrate to 
$$
y(x)-y(0)=\int_0^xy'(s)ds=\int_0^x f(s,y(s))ds.
$$
Transform this fixed-point equation for continuous functions into a fixed-point iteration in the trivial way.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating both sides of the equation you get
$$y(x)=x^4+\int_0^x t y^2(t) \, dt$$
Your goal is to find a sequence of function which converges to the solution
starting with $y_0(x)=0$

And using the given  integral equation to get the $n+1th$ from the $nth$

$$y_{n+1}(x)=x^4+\int_0^x t y^2_n(t) \, dt$$

We get for $n=0$
$$y_{1}(x)=x^4+\int_0^x t \cdot 0\, dt=x^4$$

for $n=1$
$$y_{2}(x)=x^4+\int_0^x t \cdot t^8 \, dt=\frac{x^{10}}{10}+x^4$$
for $n=2$
$$y_{3}(x)=x^4+\int_0^x t\cdot \left( t^4 + \frac{t^{10}}{10}\right)^2 \, dt=\frac{x^{22}}{2200}+\frac{x^{16}}{80}+\frac{x^{10}}{10}+x^4$$
for $n=3$
$$y_{4}(x)=x^4+\int_0^x t \cdot y_3(t) \, dt$$
This sequence converges to the solution
which is approximately
$$y(x)\approx \frac{x^{46}}{222640000}+\frac{x^{40}}{3520000}+\frac{87 x^{34}}{11968000}+\frac{3 x^{28}}{24640}+\frac{7 x^{22}}{4400}+\frac{x^{16}}{80}+\frac{x^{10}}{10}+x^4$$
it's not that easy

Reference

[Application of fixed point method for solving nonlinear Volterra-Hammerstein integral equation](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwij4rfW4-PUAhVOKVAKHZG9A_AQFgg3MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scientificbulletin.upb.ro%2Frev_docs_arhiva%2Ffull0fd_243447.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEAj_RaDmgxTdnSnRkF8rHn3-Xmig)